# помогите пожалуйста с owl-carousel2

Tags: javascript, slider, owl-carousel

Помогите с помощью плагина owl-carousel2 сделать autoplay через 3 секунды

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[![

```js
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:100,
    autoplayHoverPause:true
});
$('.play').on('click',function(){
    owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay',[1000])
})
$('.stop').on('click',function(){
```

```html
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="bg__header">
    <h1 class="bg__header-title">Почувствуй атмосферу</h1>
    <h2 class="bg__header-title bg__header-title-h2">Bar neBAr</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="bg__header">
    <h1 class="bg__header-title">Почувствуй</h1>
    <h2 class="bg__header-title bg__header-title-h2">Bar neBAr</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="bg__header">
    <h1 class="bg__header-title"> атмосферу</h1>
    <h2 class="bg__header-title bg__header-title-h2">Bar neBAr</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT6x8.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT6x8.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установи опцию autoplayTimeout: 3000

Comment: Diman2000zver я это делал, проблема была в другом, но спасибо за попытку помочь